# C#: switch vs method overload in factory class

Tags: c#, performance, switch-statement, overloading

Given classes:

```
enum ThingEnum { A,B,C}

interface IThing { }

class A : IThing { }

class B : IThing { }

class C: IThing { }
```

I have two implementations of `IThingFactory` in my head. One using `switch`:

```
class ThingFactory
{
    public IThing MakeThing(ThingEnum type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ThingEnum.A:
                return new A();
                break;
            case ThingEnum.B:
                return new B();
                break;
            case ThingEnum.C:
                return new C();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Another using abstraction and method overload:

```
class ThingFactory
{
    public IThing Make(A a)
    {
        return new A();
    }

    public IThing Make(B a)
    {
        return new B();
    }

    public IThing Make(C a)
    {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. which implementation is faster,
2. which is more readable/easier to understand,
3. which will you use and why?

Comment: You can't do method overloads based on enum value. How exactly are you planning to differentiate between them? And what is exact semantic of the enum and returned classes?

Comment: As an aside, IThingFactory should be called ThingFactory because it's a class not an interface.

Comment: try to compile both and you'll get your answer...

Comment: @JCode, do your classes have names as in ThingEnum?

Comment: @Oxoron, in this example yes, but in code I do no.

Comment: @JCode, so you need a code which will describe relations enumValue - class. They are almost the same by performance, but variations of the first variant are easier to read. Just create unit-tests, which check all enum values for related classes, and all classes of IThing for related enum value, if you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would really suggest as IoC container for your approach.
Anyway, maybe you just have some classes where you want to do ensure something happens to the class after the `.ctor`, this approach will work and you don't have to use a switch.

```
class IThingFactory
{
    public IThing MakeThing<T>() where T : IThing, new()
    {
         var thing = new T();
         thing.Init(); // has to be part of the IThing interface.
         return thing;
    }
}
```

a more generic approach would be this

```
class IThingFactory
{
    private IDictionary<Type, Func<IThing>> factories = new Dictionary<Type, Func<IThing>>();

    public void Register(Type t, Func<IThing> factory);
    {
         if(!typeof(IThing).IsAssignableFrom(t))
             throw new ArgumentException("This is not a thing");
         this.factories.Add(t, factory);
    }

    public void Register<T>() where T : IThing, new()
    {
        this.Register<T>(() => new T());
    }

    public void Register<T>(Func<IThing> factory) where T : IThing
    {
        this.Register(typeof(T), factory);
    }

    public IThing MakeThing(Type type);
    {
        if (!factories.ContainsKey(type))
             throw new ArgumentException("I don't know this thing");
        return factories[type]();
    }
}

public void Main()
{
     var factory = new IThingFactory();
     factory.Register(typeof(A), () => new A());
     factory.Register<B>();
     factory.Register<C>(() => new C("Test"));
     var instance = factory.MakeThing(typeof(A));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection is more maintainable.

1. Never use `switch` because when you add new class, you have to modify this switch statement as well.
2. Second approach is not acceptable. Where are a, b, c from? You have to `new` them without factory method.

Also check some [IoC containers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

Comment: reflection is good, but also runtime error-prone, needs right convention and consistency, easy to loose control and get into troubles, not the fastest either

Comment: I agree. That's why I mentioned IoC container as well. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
internal static class Factory
{
    internal static Dictionary<ThingEnum, Func<IThing>> ctors = new Dictionary<ThingEnum, Func<IThing>>
    {
        {ThingEnum.A, () => new A() },
        {ThingEnum.B, () => new B() },
        {ThingEnum.C, () => new C() }
    };

    internal static IThing MakeThing(ThingEnum type)
    {
        return ctors[type]();
    }
}
```

it's more laconic then first variant. Performance will be almost the same.

Comment: basically same as switch, just more complicated, needs editing with each next subtype

Comment: @mikus, you are right. It's difficult to get easier answer for the task of binding two varieties of objects.
The first variant: do bindings manually. Each answer is just a variation.

The other variant: fill reflection during build process. Get all inheritors of IThing, values of enum, and bind by the same names.

The third variant: use reflection in runtime, during factory creating, bind inheritors and enum values by names.

Last variants have a problem: names must be the same.

There are more clever and difficult variants, but even variants above are too difficult for this task.